# Is iSQL more safer than MYSQL. And what is the difference between these.Is there use difference

Tags: odbc, isql

Do somebody know difference between these to. Or could link in some good resources where i can find more about iSQL.

Is iSQL safer than MYSQL?

I have tried google and youtube but dont find much abourt this.

Answer (score 0):

iSQL and MySQL are completely different software.

According theirs documentation [iSQL](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-isql/#:%7E:text=isql%20is%20a%20command%20line,with%20built%2Din%20Unicode%20support.)  is  unixODBC command-line interactive SQL tool. [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) is an open-source relational database management system (RDBMS).

So those programs can not be compared by theirs properties.